# How can I get my TCP listener service to terminate correctly?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services, visual-studio-2010

I'm writing a Windows service which starts a TCP listener.  The core code works fine, but I'm having several problems with the mechanics of a Windows service.

Right now, when my service starts up, it creates a thread and starts the TCP listener in the thread.  Then, when the service stops, it terminates that thread:

```
Public Class txnSocketService
    Inherits System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

    Private listenerThread As Thread


    Public Sub New()
        Me.ServiceName = "txnSocketService"
        Me.CanStop = True
        Me.CanPauseAndContinue = True
        Me.AutoLog = True
    End Sub

    Shared Sub Main()
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(New txnSocketService)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        listenerThread = New Thread(AddressOf pmtListener.Main)
        listenerThread.IsBackground = True
        listenerThread.Start()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        listenerThread.Abort()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        '
        'txnSocketService
        '
        Me.ServiceName = "txnSocketService"

    End Sub
End Class
```

Starting up works fine.  If I stop the service, however, the service process doesn't terminate.  What am I doing wrong?

[By the way, I'm currently doing this on VS2010 Beta 2, if that matters.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of terminating the thread with Thread.Abort() you should implement some shutdown() method that gracefully closes the socket.

e.g.

```
Public Class pmtListener
  Protected shutingdown As Boolean = False
  ' [...] '
  Public Sub Shutdown()
    shutingdown = True
    socketListen.Close()
  End Sub
  Sub Main()
    Dim socketAccepted As Socket
    shutingdown = False
    socketListen.Listen(3)
    While Not shutingdown
      Try
        socketAccepted = socketListen.Accept()
        ' do something with socketAccepted '
        socketAccepted.Close()
        socketAccepted = Nothing
      Catch ex As SocketException
        If shutingdown Then
          ' ignoring it '
        End If
      End Try

    End While
  End Sub
```

When Shutdown() calls socketListen.Close() and the worker thread is currently waiting for a new connection a SocketExcpetion will be raised. We just ignore that.
In your OnStop() method you first give the pmtListener instance a chance to shutdown gracefully by calling myListener.Shutdown() (which then sets the shutingdown flag and closes the socket) and then wait (up to) a certain timespan (e.g. one second). Should the thread still be alive try to terminate it.

```
Public Class txnSocketService
  Inherits System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

  Protected myListener as pmtListern
  Protected listenerThread As Thread

  ' [...] '
  Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    myListener = new pmtListener
    listenerThread = New Thread(AddressOf myListener.Main)
    listenerThread.IsBackground = True
    listenerThread.Start()
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    myListener.Shutdown()
    listenerThread.Join(1000) ' give it a second '
    If listenerThread.IsAlive Then
      listenerThread.Abort()
    End If
  End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, let's say pmtListener has a shutdown() method.  What would it look like to call it?  Do I need to rejoin with the spawned thread?

Comment: Give me a second or two for an example ...I'm not a VB developer ;-)  Short version: Don't use a static method (shared sub?) but an instance of pmtListener (dim myListener as new pmtListener() ?) and start the thread on its Main() method (new Thread(AddressOf myListener.Main))

Comment: The example seem to work (only tested as a console app, not a service). Socket.Accept() calls (unmanaged) winsock code that isn't affected by the ThreadAbortException. I wonder if there's way to "make it aware". Note to self: That took too long. practice more vb.net. It _is_ dotnet.

Comment: I would still do it this way, but I think technically the Join() and the Abort() failsafe are not necessary since the thread is a background thread, which should automatically terminate when the process goes away.

Comment: If that's reliable for a service then yes, get rid of the call to Abort(). But I'd keep the Join(timeout). A maximum delay of one second shouldn't hurt if it gives the thread a chance to clean up first.

Comment: Thanks all, this is very helpful!  My Listener uses the .net class TCPListener instead of Socket.Accept()-- does this solve the issue with ThreadAbortException?  Initial tests say no.

Comment: Then use the TCPListener's Stop() method, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.stop.aspx

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm doing.  Thanks!